# What work on Sharanagati did Thirukannamangai Andan compose?

Tags: vishnu, history, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, sharanagati

The Alwars (also spelled Azhwars) are a group of 12 ancient Vaishnava saints who lived in Tamil Nadu and are famous for their poetry in praise of Vishnu. The 4000 verses of the Alwars were compiled by the Vaishnava Acharya Nathamuni into a book called the Naalayira Divya Prabhandam, which is considered by many to be the "Dravida Veda", or South Indian Veda. It's the principles and beliefs embodied in the Alwars' poems that Nathamuni used to found what we now call the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I am a member).  Now Nathamuni had many famous shishyas, including Uyyakondar and Kurugai Kavalappan.  But my question is about another shishya of Nathamuni, Thirukannamangai Andan, known in Sanskrit as Srikrishna Lakshminatha.

Once Thirukannamanagai Andan observed two people fighting over their dogs.  The first person’s dog bit the second person’s dog, in response to which the second person killed the first person’s dog, in response to which the first person killed the second person and then killed himself.  Thirukannamangai Andan realized that if that is how far a person would go to protect his dog, there are no limits to how far Sriman Narayana would go to protect us.  So Thirukannamangai Andan performed Sharanagati, aka Prapatti, complete surrender to Vishnu as a means to attain Moksha.  He gave everything up and spent the rest of his life in the Bhaktavatsala Perumal Vishnu temple in Thirukannamangai, and then at the end of his life he turned into a dog and merged with the Bhaktavatsala Perumal statue.

But [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=jI2PUAa8B8oC&lpg=PA94&dq=divyasuri&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false) says that Thirukannamangai Andan did not merely perform Sharanagati, he also composed a work on the subject:

> **Srikrishna Lakshminatha, disciple of Nathamuni, wrote an extensive work on the doctrine of Prapatti.** He was born at a place called Krishnamangala.  He was well-versed in the Vedas, and was a specialist in Vedanta and also a great devotee, who constantly employed himself in chanting the name of Vishnu.  He often used to go about naked and live on food that was thrown to him.  The hagiologists say that he entered into the image of the temple and became one with God.

My question is, what is this “extensive work” of Thirukannamangai Andan on the subject of Sharanagati?  I’m pretty sure the work is lost, since the earliest surviving Sri Vaishnava philosophical works are those of Nathamuni’s grandson Yamunacharya (which you can read [here](https://archive.org/details/yamunacharya)).  But do we at least know the name of the work, and are there any surviving quotes from it in later Sri Vaishnava works?